# Site to Site VPN Gateway - Checkpoint R60 and OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, checkpoint

I'm new with this kind of stuff, I'm usually only configure VPN client connect to server, but this time I have to make Site to Site VPN gateway, and I'm very clueless about this. Anyone know where I can learn this kind of stuff ? Also Is it possible to connect site to site vpn between checkpoint r60 and openvpn ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. Checkpoint uses IPsec, while OpenVPN uses it's own protocol (actually, it uses ipsec, but uses SSL for authentication, rather than IKE). There is probably an implementation of Ipsec for your platform that you can use however.

Comment: How about if change from OpenVPN into Windows IPSec, is it still possible to create site to site vpn gateway?

Comment: yes, that should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSwan is what you need to connect a site-to-site from Checkpoint to Linux.

http://www.openswan.org/

Comment: I've just read that openswan no longer support cehckpoint based on the documentation i've read in openswan. do you have specific site to show  openswan support for checkpoint? Thanks

Comment: Hi Funky, What documentation were you reading? Can you send a link? Here's the interop page from openswan's site: http://wiki.openswan.org/index.php/Interop/InteroperatingCheckpoint